# Integrating of Analytics doesn´t work

Tags: android, google-analytics

I try to integrate google Analytics to my Application but it doesn´t work.

This is my `Activity`:

```
public class InhaltsverzeichnisActivity extends Activity {

private SharedPreferencesManager prefs; //added

private InterstitialAd Interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inhaltsverzeichnis);

    prefs = new SharedPreferencesManager(this); //get SharedPreferencesManager  instance
    int t = prefs.retrieveInt("theme", 0); //get stored theme, zero is default
    ThemeUtils.setTheme(t);  //Set the stored theme, will default to Black

    Tracker t1 = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t1.setScreenName("Inhaltsverzeichnis");
    t1.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

    Interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    Interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    Interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        ;
        Interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                 displayInterstitial();
                 Interstitial.show();
    }
        });
}

protected void displayInterstitial() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    public void onDismissScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onLeaveApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onPresentScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
       protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(InhaltsverzeichnisActivity.this).reportActivityStart(this);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onStop() {
          super.onStop();
          GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(InhaltsverzeichnisActivity.this).reportActivityStop(this);
       }
```

If I put the OnStart and OnStop method over the Interstitial Ad , Analytics works, but the Interstitial Ad goes crazy and appears every second again,

hope anyone can help me to solve this problem thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "crashes" can you post your LogCat error please?

Comment: Have you tried to clear project or rebuild it?

Comment: Yes but it's not working

Comment: Are you starting your analytics on AnalyticsSampleApp OnCreate?